# How to create a constructor in another class that will read a file, then instantiate it in the main method?

Tags: java, swing, file, constructor, jfilechooser

I'm trying to create a constructor with a parameter of file type (ex, public TextRead(File textFile)). How would I write this constructor so that when instantiated in the main method would take in the file I chose in the main method using JFileChooser?

I guess to put it simply, how would I take what file I selected using the file chooser and put it in the parameter of the constructor? How would I need to set up the constructor for this to work?

```
//My main method has this
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    Scanner in = null;
    if(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
        //Constructor goes here to read the file I selected using the file chooser
    }
}

//The class that has the constructor
public class TextRead
{
    public TextRead(File textFile)
    {
        //What do I need to write here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html). You only need to use `fileChooser.getSelectedFile()`. Then your code should look like this

```
//My main method has this
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    Scanner in = null;
    if(fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        //Constructor goes here to read the file I selected using the file chooser
        TextRead textRead = new TextRead(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
    }
}

//The class that has the constructor
public class TextRead {
    private File file;  

    public TextRead(File textFile) {
        this.file = textFile; 
    }
}
```